# Retrieve date and time from UIDatePicker iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I want to retrieve date and time in format e.g "Friday May 31, 2013 12:00 pm". How can I achieve that with NSDateFormatter?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
NSDate *myDate = datePicker.date;

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"cccc, MMM d, hh:mm aa"];
NSString *prettyVersion = [dateFormat stringFromDate:myDate];
```