# UIDatePicker With year , month , date and time

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to get the year,date, month and time on using single UIDatePicker.

code i implemented is

```
//_datePicker.minimumDate = Date;
_datePicker.minuteInterval = 15;
if (app.datePickerInt == 0) {

    [_datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
    _datePicker.minuteInterval = 15;

}
if (app.datePickerInt == 1) {

    [_datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];
    _datePicker.minuteInterval = 15;

}
```

my requirement is i need both date,year,month and time in one picker.

Comment: please check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559541/retrieve-date-and-time-from-uidatepicker-ios   or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459746/uidatepicker-has-a-date-and-time-option-but-how-to-display-both-in-an-app might be helpful. try this.

Comment: if you need all you need to implement in UIPickerView ,

Comment: see this link may be help with you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089618/how-to-prepare-uipickerview-with-months-and-years-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

Use datepicker mode date and time, like :

```
     [_datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime];
```

And use date formatter

```
NSDate *date = datePicker.date;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```